# Will I run into performance issues if I use a blob field as primary key in SQLite?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have a sqlite database where all the primary keys are GUIDs.  Currently they are stored as fixed length strings but I want to store them as blobs because it simplifies the code for storing and retrieving data.  I converted part of the database and everything is functioning as expected.  However, I'm not sure if I will run into performance issues.

For example, would a statement like this be faster on strings than blobs?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.parent_id
```

My intuitions says no, but that doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: My intuitions say yes, but that doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: can SQLite index a blob?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to find out is to run the queries against a profiler/SQLite's timer.  Setup a test and run the query 1000 times with string, then 1000 times as a blob.  Winner is the fastest.

Intuition is one thing, hard data is another.

Comment: Also try it with BINARY, which is a better match for your GUID data than a text string.

Comment: Dominic: Did you do this? Did what was your result?

Comment: I ran this sort of test (via Qt's sqlite driver, sqlite3) and searching for a 36-character string UUID was ~4 % slower than a corresponding 16 byte compact UUID blob. I'm in favor of the string version because it's easier to debug.

Comment: Nice answer but not really a valuable one. The fact it as been accepted suggests the experiment has been undertaken (by the question author, @lawrence-barsanti presumably) and if so it is *very desirable to share the result please!* :-)

Comment: For anyone wondering, I wrote this test using Python 3 and SQLite3: https://gist.github.com/caioariede/7d765aa37241e1ccd56d5bc1631a3d18

Comment: Please look at this for data:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337324/how-to-efficient-insert-and-fetch-uuid-in-core-data/11337522#11337522

Answer (score 0):

I think AIEE and if I were you I'd be storing GUIDs in a pair of Integer types on SQLITE (SQLITE INTEGER is 64 bits).

However in this case blob might actually work better.

LFSR is right, profile it.

Answer (score -6):

### Why you shouldn't use it

A primary key is often indexed and used for sorting. A `BLOB` cannot be indexed which makes it the slowest of all datatypes. In fact, it is the worst choice as primary key and most databases, including the SQL99 standard, disallow it.

The problem with a `BLOB` is that its datatype is not known by the database (a `BLOB` should only be used for anything undefined, like an logo, an image, a word document, that can only be stored as binary data). Hence it cannot optimize it. Another problem is display. A blob cannot simply be displayed as text.

Most SQL implementations do not allow `BLOB` fields compared, but SQLite allows it. However, it converts anything your compare it to into a blob and then compares it bit by bit.

### Best alternative

The best option for a primary key column in SQLite is to use the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as described here;: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid it gives the best performance (it is already there as the `rowid` column, it is just aliased).

### Conclusion

To answer your question: yes, it influences the performance badly. But more importantly, it will make it very hard to manage your tables well. Use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, it is really the best, guaranteed unique and is blazingly fast.

Comment: Actually BLOBs *can* be indexed in SQLite.

Comment: Ah, good, didn't know. Nevertheless, why would one want to index binary data? If you store icons or images, you could search for them based on the image itself, perhaps in such a scenario? But intriguing to know that it _is_ possible :)

Comment: @Abel thanks for the detailed response.  @finnw thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Abel Regarding why anyone would want to do that... You can use SQLite as a simple NOSQL database by using a table with two BLOBs "key" and "value". Also there are plenty cases where you want to store a hash code in a table in an indexed column. What people usually do if there is no indexable "binary" type is to store the hash code as hex (or base64) encoded a string. Which is fine, except it's a waste of space.

Comment: @Abel You can store images and use a hash (blob), like SHA-1, as a primary key to look up the records, or to avoid duplicates.

Comment: While i disagree with Abel's reasoning, I think his answer was right. IMHO, the best solution is to have an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY on the table and an Unique Index on the BLOB. An INTEGER PRIMARY KEY uses SQLite's internal ROWID, providing a quick way to access and manipulate the data.

Comment: @KevinDelaney the main reason this is attractive is that a very common type of primary key is a UUID. If you can store the UUID as a number as opposed to a string you would save 9x the space.

Comment: IPAddresses, hashes, guids and more are great indexable blobs

Comment: i use BLOB PRIMARY KEY here to look for hash collisions, https://gist.github.com/divinity76/3eb1846fb5478120afd6e37d251a381f