# Using UUIDs in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, uuid

Is it possible to use [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) values as a primary key in SQLite? I'm finding extremely limited information on the topic, so I'm not sure if SQLite even supports a UUID data type. Should I be storing a UUID as a string?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

SQLite allows to use any [data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) as primary key.

UUIDs can be stored either as strings (which are human-readable) or as 16-byte BLOBs (which might be faster if the records are so small that the difference matters).

Comment: Are either of those data types more efficient than the other for storing UUIDs?

Comment: For other readers… the human-readable 36-character hex string looks like this: `988097c8-3f9c-4ecf-9d1d-64701bb9764c`

Comment: UUID BLOB vs TEXT matters the file size, however, the speed of insert and query is about the same, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11337522/254109

Answer (score 73):

CL's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278095) is correct but kind of skirts the issue at hand. As mentioned, a column (or multiple columns) of any type can be used as a primary key. So you *could* store the UUID as a formatted, human-readable string and make that your table's key. And since a UUID is just a 128-bit integer, you could also store the integer's bytes as a BLOB, which saves space and *might* be slightly faster.

But to more directly answer what I believe is the question at hand, no, **SQLite does not have any features that directly support UUID's**. When SQLite creates a table, it uses a column's declared type to determine which of the five underlying [storage classes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (integer, real, text, blob or null) it will use. After the table is created, a column's type isn't used and the column's behavior is determined entirely by its storage class. There are no UUID-specific column types or storage classes. There also don't seem to be any [functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) available for converting to and from a formatted UUID string. To get your UUID's bytes, you'll want to see what methods are provided by the language your application is written in. For example, Java's [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class, Apple's [NSUUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid/1411420-getbytes), or Swift's [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid).

Answer (score 24):

There is now an extension for sqlite that creates valid uuids as per https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/uuid.c

Comment: How do you add an extension?

Comment: a bit fiddly.. see here for details https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html#:~:text=An%20SQLite%20extension%20is%20a,using%20the%20sqlite3_load_extension()%20API.

Comment: After downloading the file, `gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib uuid.c -o uuid.c.dylib` You can then in sqlite3 `SELECT load_extension('uuid.c');`

Answer (score 10):

I needed an implementation for UUID in sqlite, since it's not a native feature, so here is a trick that I came across in the internet. 
SQLite doesn't support UUID, so the idea is to create a function that would generate a UUID using the `randomblob()` function

```
select lower(hex( randomblob(4)) || '-' || hex( randomblob(2))
         || '-' || '4' || substr( hex( randomblob(2)), 2) || '-'
         || substr('AB89', 1 + (abs(random()) % 4) , 1)  ||
         substr(hex(randomblob(2)), 2) || '-' || hex(randomblob(6)))
```

This will ensure that you will have a UUID that can be stored in your table as `varchar`, so now to implement it. SQLite doesn't store functions, so  you can use a trigger that can be called once a new record is inserted in your table

```
CREATE TABLE UUID_TABLE(
   id varchar(500),
   name varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (name),
   CONSTRAINT rid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoGenerateGUID_RELATION_3
AFTER INSERT ON UUID_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.relation_id IS NULL)
BEGIN
   UPDATE UUID_TABLE SET relation_id = (select lower(hex( randomblob(4)) || '-' ||      hex( randomblob(2))
             || '-' || '4' || substr( hex( randomblob(2)), 2) || '-'
             || substr('AB89', 1 + (abs(random()) % 4) , 1)  ||
             substr(hex(randomblob(2)), 2) || '-' || hex(randomblob(6))) ) WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

So whenever a new row is inserted, by default a NULL value will be affected to the id, and after that the trigger will modify it to a new UUID value stored as varchar.

Solution inspired from: [solution source](https://www.kittell.net/code/auto-increment-auto-generate-guid/)

Comment: what I meant is that UUID is not defined as a data type in sqlite , check this https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
The accepted answer suggest that UUID can be stored as a string in sqlite. 
Unlike postgresql that support UUID as a datatype, thing that can help you to generate UUID automatically

Comment: @NicoHaase that accepted answer literally says: UUIDs can be stored as strings or as blobs. I.e.: there is no first-class support of UUIDs in sqlite. There are many ways to inerpret what kaygi22 said, but you can reasonably interpret it as being sensible.

Comment: For large volumes of small records, storing UUIDs as strings will take up a disproportionate amount of storage - it probably isn't optimal for indices either. I expect you could do better by storing 128-bit (16-byte) blobs, using a similar technique, but with bitwise operators to create valid UUID v4 bits - and then convert to/from formatted strings in your client layer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about using it as default field, but if someone needs to generate unique value in sqlite query following approach [suggested here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/uuid-generation-in-sqlite-td35137.html) can be used:

*The randomblob(N) function return an N-byte blob containing pseudo-random 
bytes. If N is less than 1 then a 1-byte random blob is returned. 
Hint: applications can generate globally unique identifiers using this 
function together with hex() and/or lower() like this:*

```
hex(randomblob(16))
```

or

```
lower(hex(randomblob(16)))
```

Comment: UUID is not a `randomblob(16)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22725697/254109 If you do not need exact UUID, then `randomblob` is sufficient.

Comment: Pseudo-random bytes are _not_ the same as a UUID.