# UUID type error when using NSBatchInsertRequest

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm using `NSBatchInsertRequest` to save an array of data to Core Data and the model has an attribute `id` which is of type `UUID`. when I attempt to execute the batch insert I get `id is not valid` error, however when I change the type of `id` to `String` everything works fine.

It might worth mentioning that, when I try to save the array one by one without using `NSBatchInsertRequest`, `id` being `UUID` is not an issue.

I was wondering whether it's a known issue or I'm missing something?

Appreciate any guidance!

Edit I:
As mentioned in the comment section `NSBatchInsertRequest` works directly with SQlite and according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277735/using-uuids-in-sqlite) it is better to save `UUID` as `String`

Comment: I don’t really know but the batch insert is executed directly at the Sql level so could it be that SQLite doesn’t support the UUID type?

Comment: I think you are right, I did come across some questions which talked about using UUID in sqlite. I'll link those questions to my post. Thanks!