# How can I read a `uuid` from a column in a sqlite3 db using sqlite-net-pcl in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, guid, sqlite-net-pcl

I have a database schema that I do not control (it's a sqlite3 file exported from a desktop application that I need to interoperate with), that contains UUIDs for some of the columns. I'm using `sqlite-net-pcl` in a Xamarin.Forms app, and I cannot work out how to successfully read these columns. Here's what I've tried:

- using the sqlite3 command line, I've confirmed that the schema has type `uuid` for the relevant column, and using `select count(distinct uuidcolumn) from mytable;` I've confirmed that there are values for each row. (The column is nullable which is relevant for the code snippet below but in practice all the rows have non-null values)
- I have this model object:

```
namespace brahms.Model
{
    [Table("mytable")]
    public class MyTable
    {
        [Column("uuidcolumn")]
        public Guid UUIDColumn { get; }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
        [Column("recordid")]
        public int RecordID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- if I fetch an object using `database.Query<MyTable>()` queries, `UUIDColumn` is *always* equal to `Guid.Empty`.
- I tried switching the type in the class definition to `Byte[]`; it's always `null`.
- I tried switching the type in the class definition to `string`; it's always `null`.
- Same applies to the `UInt16[]` type (the GUID might be stored as a blob of 16-bit words, so I tried that type too)

How can I read the values in `uuid`-typed columns using `sqlite-net-pcl`?

Comment: what is the actual type of the column in the db?

Comment: @Jason the type is only given as `uuid` in the schema, I've read that [there isn't really a uuid type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043264/6105673) but I don't know what that means. I'd guess `blob`, as I can't read the content as strings, but I can't read it as bytes either.

Comment: Thinking `blob` made me think to try `UInt16[]` as the mapped type, which also doesn't work.

Comment: it sounds like byte[] is the correct approach - https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/412

Comment: @Jason I thought so, not sure why it doesn't work in my case. I'd normally break out a minimally-reproducing test project, but because I don't control the schema there's not much minimisation I can do :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on using the ORM features in `sqlite-net-pcl` and used this query:

```
db.executeScalar<byte[]>('select hex(uuidcolumn) from mytable where recordid=1');
```

What I get back is 72 bytes, which appear to represent the 36 ASCII characters in a string representation of a Guid (every so often one of the characters is `2D`, which is `-` in the ASCII set). So I think that the backing store is a blob but one that's storing the text representation of the Guid, which is weird, but I'll be able to reconstruct the Guid from here.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363456/6105673) and getting that blob as a string, I ended up with this implementation:

```cs
        public Guid GetUUIDColumn()
        {
            string dbRep = _database.ExecuteScalar<string>("select hex(uuidcolumn) from mytable where recordid = ?", RecordID);
            if (dbRep == null || dbRep == string.Empty) return Guid.Empty;
            var bytes = new byte[dbRep.Length / 2];
            // each pair of bytes represents the ASCII code (in hexadecimal) for a character in the string representation of a Guid.
            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(dbRep.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
            }

            string asString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            return new Guid(asString);  
        }
```